# ORACLE SQL: Replace part of text field ignoring case

Tags: sql, oracle, text

I need to replace a path stored in an Oracle DB text field. However paths have been specified with different cases (ie MYPATH, MyPath, Mypath, mypath). When using a combination of `REPLACE` and `UPPER`, it does not work as I need it to, ie:

```
UPDATE Actions 
SET Destination = REPLACE(UPPER(Destination), 'MYPATH', 'My_New_Path')
```

This does the replace but leaves everything in upper case - even for the rows where there is nothing to replace

BEFORE: `MyPath\FileName` - AFTER: `My_New_Path\FILENAME`
BEFORE: `DummyText` - AFTER: `DUMMYTEXT`

What I really need is to replace any occurrence of MyPath, regardless of the case to My_New_Path, without touching the casing on other rows or other part of the field

Any ideas? I have been scratching my head to no avail...

PS: Working with Oracle 9...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this:

```
UPDATE Actions
SET Destination = SUBSTR(Destination,1,INSTR(UPPER(Destination), 'MYPATH')-1)
                  || 'My_New_Path'
                  || SUBSTR(Destination,INSTR(UPPER(Destination), 'MYPATH')+6)
WHERE UPPER(Destination) LIKE '%MYPATH%';
```

Comment: Darn, Tony types fater than me!

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest using regexp_replace() but IIRC that's not available in Oracle 9.

Something like this then:

```
UPDATE atable
SET afield=SUBSTR(afield, 1, (INSTR(UPPER(afield),'old')-1) 
   || 'new' 
   || SUBSTR(afield, INSTR(UPPER(afield),'old')+LENGHT('old'), LENGTH(afield))
WHERE afield LIKE '%' || 'old' || '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination + tweaking of the 2 answers made it work:

> UPDATE actions SET
>   Destination=SUBSTR(Destination, 1,
>   (INSTR(UPPER(Destination),'OLD')-1))
>   || 'NEW'    || SUBSTR(Destination,
>   INSTR(UPPER(Destination),'OLD')+LENGTH('OLD'),
>   LENGTH(Destination)) WHERE
>   UPPER(Destination) LIKE '%OLD%';

Thanks guys! - I would vote both answers up but I just signed up and don't have enough reputation...

Comment: as the questioner, you should select one of them as the accepted answer - you don't need any rep to do that.